# AndroidManifest.xml is getting corrupted when a new activity is created

Tags: android, android-manifest

When i create a new activity for my project, my new activity has errors, i think they are related to the androidmanifest.xml which get some weird lines at start and at end.

This are the lines that eclipse says that has errors

<<<<<<< Original
 , >>>>>>> Added

And this is the entire androidmanifest.xml

```
<<<<<<< Original
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="moran.jonathan.pizzeria"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="moran.jonathan.pizzeria.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="moran.jonathan.pizzeria.Menu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_menu" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
=======
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <application>
        <activity android:name=".Menu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_menu"
            android:parentActivityName="moran.jonathan.pizzeria.MainActivity">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="moran.jonathan.pizzeria.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
>>>>>>> Added
```

What could be happening?

Thanks in advance

EDIT WITH USEFUL INFO:

Never try to create an activity called Menu, as it seems to be some kind of reserved word and this is why this problem appears

Comment: why are u adding two tags of manifest?

Comment: Thats the point, the ide does it automatically when i create the new activity :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="moran.jonathan.pizzeria"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="moran.jonathan.pizzeria.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="moran.jonathan.pizzeria.Menu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_menu" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: checking the name on the androidmanifest file, i see that the name dfoes not contain the name of the packages at this line

<activity android:name=".Menu"

while others activities of the project are like this

android:name="moran.jonathan.pizzeria.MainActivity"

Probably thats why the manifest got separated but i still dont how how happened as i created the new activity automatically on the project

Comment: Welcome Zaguaiio Soshi Silva

Comment: I found the root cause of the problem, this happens when the activity you create you name it "Menu" as it seems to be a kind of android reserved word

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have merged a conflicted file in git. Remove those lines and remove the repeat code and commit again:

```
<<<<<<< Original

// (1) this is your original Manifest code

=======

// (2) this is the new code.

>>>>>>> Added
```

NOTE: Either remove (1) or (2) depending on you need. and remove the extra lines

Comment: This is the certain root of the problem, isn't something related to eclipse nor android system adding strange characters in the file.

Comment: @MetalCraneo Git does this. This occurs in case of conflicts when you previous version code and current version code have conflicts.