# Two manifest tags get created when I add an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

With everything checked, when I create a new activity two manifest tags are created automatically and it shows an error. Should I uncheck something when creating a new activity before clicking finish in the preview section? My manifest code is below:

```
  <<<<<<< Original
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
         <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         package="com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit"
         android:versionCode="1"
         android:versionName="1.0" >

         <uses-sdk
           android:minSdkVersion="8"
           android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <application
           android:allowBackup="true"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit.FlashlightActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_flashlight"
            android:parentActivityName="com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>







=======
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <application>
        <activity android:name=".FlashlightActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_flashlight"
            >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
>>>>>>> Added
```

Those `<<<<<<< Original` and other tags were created automatically. Why is it doing this?

Comment: Post the error that you got.

Comment: Looks like the output of some diff tool. How you get that there is not clear from the question.

Comment: error i got:

[2013-12-15 19:45:33 -com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for D:\softwares\eclipse workspace\ToolKit\AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.

Comment: my problem is exactly the same as this here but i don't have any activity named "Menu"
what might be the reason causing this?
IDE inserts the second manifest tags automatically when i create the new activity

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486943/androidmanifest-xml-is-getting-corrupted-when-a-new-activity-is-created?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.FlashLight." />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

I don't know what IDE you are using ~ I am going to assume the Eclipse IDE Android bundle. When you create a new activity in the android manifest you need an intent filter within the activity xml files. So when you call a new activity in the src java files. You should have something like the code above in yours, but the 'FlashLight' at the end of android:name can be anything you want as long as you remember it and it makes sense. This is what seems to be missing from your code.

A quick work around would be to delete everything but:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit.FlashlightActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_flashlight"

</activity>
```

and then add in that snippet of code at the top.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit.FlashlightActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_flashlight"

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.FlashLight." />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i'm using Eclipse Juno
i created the new activity by right clicking layout->new->....
i'm new to android programming.
how do i post an image..so that I could give some screenshots.
Thanks.

Comment: You can edit your original post and add an image in. I recommend that if you are using a 32-bit machine that your migrate over to Android Studio, or if you are using a 64-bit machine that you use intellij. They are very pleasant to work with android projects and the android manifest updates automatically. All you would have to do is change the action name every time you call a new activity.

Comment: error i got: [2013-12-15 19:45:33 -com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for D:\softwares\eclipse workspace\ToolKit\AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.


my problem is exactly the same as this here but i don't have any activity named "Menu" what might be the reason causing this? IDE inserts the second manifest tags automatically when i create the new activity

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486943/androidmanifest-xml-is-getting-corrupted-when-a-new-activity-is-created?rq=1

Comment: I edited the manifest file like you said and it worked.Thanks a ton.
but why is it happening? All I did was create a new activity.

Comment: Hey, Sorry - just seen this now. A lot of programmers are very anti using WYSIWYG editors, and just code it over themselves for 2 main reasons: They have more control, and 2, they don't get code bloat. WYSIWYG editors are notorious for creating code that doesn't really need to be there. You will come to notice this when you start to position elements around the screen. That doesn't mean, don't use it. Definitely use it. It is very helpful, speedy and great to learn xml from + phones have loads of memory now! :) The reason why you were getting that error was because there was a bug in the xml